# Controller edits in devise-token-api not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I downloaded a [devise example](https://github.com/abhidsm/devise-token-api) and got it working. When trying to edit a controller `app/controllers/api/v1/sessions_controller.rb` and test it, any changes I make are not recognized by **rails**.

Neither **syntax errors** nor **legit ruby code** have any effect on the **app's behavior**. The only source file I can successfully edit is `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`.

I am coming back to **rails** after a few years away and have never seen this behavior.  Is there a controller cache, a pre-compiled module, or some other known issue causing this?

Thanks, in advance. 
***EDIT:***

This problem has been avoided in my code. Answers are still welcome to get the gist of the explanation to the problem.

Comment: This problem has left me completely baffled.